# How to encrypt User-Provided Service values in cloud foundry?

Tags: encryption, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am trying to encrypt my username and password on cloud foundry. Currently I am storing these values as a CUPS (VCAP_SERVICES).

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//spring.guru.csi0i9rgj9ws.us-east-1.rds.a‌​mazonaws.com:1521/OR‌​C
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: UserAdmin
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd
SPRING_DATASOURCE_initialize: false
```

I want to encrypt it so it would show some type of token/encryption or UUID instead of my actual username and password. How would I be able to encrypt these values so that, when I look at my VCAP_SERVICES these values would not be exposed?

**Example from Cloud Foundry Provided Service**

```
VCAP_SERVICES=
{
  cleardb: [
    {
      name: "cleardb-1",
      label: "cleardb",
      plan: "spark",
      credentials: {
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//spring.guru.csi0i9rgj9ws.us-east-1.rds.a‌​mazonaws.com:1521/OR‌​C",
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: "UserAdmin",
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: "p4ssw0rd",
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_initialize: "false"
      }
    }
  ]
```

As you can see VCAP_SERVICES above is exposed how can I encrypt it so that username and password is encrypted like example below

**Desired output**

```
 Username: hVB5j5GgdiP78xCSV9sNv4FeqQJducBxXlB81090ozYB
 Password: hVB523fff78xCSV9sNv4FeqQ341090324234fdfdsrrf
```

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt it? If you want to encrypt it, your application has to have the key to decrypt the credentials. If you have the key and the encrypted code on the same machine, it's the same as if you would have the unencrypted values. If someone gets access to your Cloudfoundry machines, your system is compromised anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I was just following the 12 factor app. Saying that no credentials should be stored in plain text.

Comment: Sure, within your central configuration management system they should be encrypted. But on the machine where the actual application is running it doesn't make sense (for the reason i already specified).

Comment: @dunni I added a image from cloud foundry how the provided services automatically have their username and pass in a UUID/token kind of encryption.

Comment: But are these really encrypted credentials and not just username and password which look like a token? If they would be encrypted, you would have to specify the key in your application to decrypt it. I doubt that this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what do you want to archive you can use spring vault mentioned by you or external vault instance with hashicorp service broker https://github.com/hashicorp/cf-vault-service-broker to retrieve/store credentials within your application in a secure way.

As a side note - the Mongodb service credentials on the screenshot are not encrypted but randomly generated by the service broker.

Most importantly - you shouldn't store/provide service credentials in your application manifest, but obtain this credentials (for binded cloudfoundry services) by parsing environment variable VCAP_SERVICES.
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#VCAP-SERVICES

External services should be presented to cloud foundry apps via CUPS https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to be using Spring already, you might want to look at Spring Cloud Config.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/

For larger projects it makes it easy to externalize and manage your configuration.  A common setup would be to store the configuration in Git (but there are other backends, including Vault), Spring Cloud Config then runs as a server and provides the configuration to your running applications (clients).  Your application (client) doesn't need to do much beyond include the Spring Cloud Config dependencies and a couple lines of config.  Settings are obtained automatically and integrated through the Environment and PropertySource abstractions, which makes for a very clean integration where you don't need to do a lot of work.

For smaller projects, it might be more overhead than you'd like.  For starts, you have to run the Spring Cloud Server.  If you only have one or two small apps, the resources to run the SCC server might be more than your app or apps total.  Complexity would be another concern.  Using SCC definitely adds some complexity and possible failure scenarios.  You'd need to understand what's happening well enough to troubleshoot when there is a problem.

What you might want to consider instead for smaller projects is simply using user provided services in CF.  These make for a central place to store your config settings (doesn't have to just be databases, could be keys and other things too).  You can then bind these to your apps to expose the configuration settings to that app.

There is some security in that Cloud Controller manages who can access your services.  I believe the information that Cloud Controller stores is also encrypted at rest, which is a plus.  That said, information is exposed to your applications via environment variables (i.e. VCAP_SERVICES) so anything in the container that can see the environment variables will be able to read your settings.

Using user provided services is one step up on environment variables.  Not really from a security stand point, but more from a management stand point.  You create the user provided service once, and can then bind it to any number of apps.  With env variables, you'd need to set those for every app.  It's more tedious, and it's prone to typos.  You can also put the service name into your manifest.yml file so it automatically binds to the app and still check that into source control.  If you were putting env variables with sensitive info into your manifest.yml, you wouldn't want to check it into source control and you'd have to be a lot more careful with that file.

Comment: If I store my credentials as VCAP_SERVICES or cups, Would I have to mask my username and password? So that it would not be exposed?

Comment: All bound service information is exposed through VCAP_SERVICES, whether it's a service from a broker or a user provided service.  It all comes through that env variable which is structured as JSON.  The variable is set by the platform, so you don't need to do anything but read and extract any information needed by your application.  When using Spring this will basically happen for you.  All you need to do is make sure that nothing can see the environment variable that should not be able to.  For example, make sure there are no debug end points in your app that would expose env variables.

Comment: Normally to see VCAP_SERVICES, you'd need to be a.) the app running in the container or b.) a user with Space Developer permissions.  The latter would let you run `cf env` to see the variable, `cf ssh` into the container or possibly another `cf` cli command that would show you the value.  Otherwise it shouldn't be accessible.

Comment: Is it possible to encrypt values when setting values as a CUPS?

Comment: You can put whatever you want into the properties that you set on a user provided service.  It could be plain text or encrypted text.  If you put encrypted text, your application will need to understand how to decrypt the text so that it can be used.  The platform just passes through the properties that you set on the user provided service.